# Where am I going wrong in my code

Tags: python

Hey guys I'm working with python I just need to know what I'm doing wrong in my code this is the snip it of the code that is incorrect from my guess:

```
Uni2Rows = []
R2Rows = 0
for rows in filter:
     R2Rows += 1
     if R2Rows > 3 and R2Rows < 34 and rows[0] is not '':
        Uni2Rows.append(rows)

GradUnderGrad = {'No.': ('Company', 'Grad', 'UnderGrad')}
for i, out2put in enumerate(Uni2Rows):
    total = 0
    for roww in Uni2Rows [11:12]:
        if roww[out2put] is not '':
            total += 1
    GradUnderGrad.append(['No', twoColumns, UniRows[11], UniRows[12]])
 print(GradUnderGrad)
```

Here is my entire code for the program and I also put how I would like my projected answer to look but what I'm actually getting

```
####please dont copy straight up its like stealing an essay some things you cant really change theres only so many ways to do it 

 ##Code by Angel M Gonzalez 

import csv
with open('scratch.csv', 'r', errors='replace') as progfile:
    progfile.close()
a = open("scratch.csv")
filter = csv.reader(a)

# Step 2: Printing
 columns = { 0: 'Company', 1: 'Booth', 2: 'Full-Time', 3: 'Full-Time Visa Sponsor', 4: 'Part-Time', 5: 'Internship', 6: 'Freshman', 7: 'Sophomore', 8: 'Junior', 9: 'Senior', 10: 'Post-Bacs', 11: 'MS', 12: 'PhD', 13: 'Alumni', }
for i in columns:
    print(i, columns[i])

 # Step 3: Filtering and Formatting
 UniRows = []
 RRows = 0
 for rows in filter:
   RRows += 1
   if RRows > 3 and RRows < 34 and rows[0] is not '':
       UniRows.append(rows)

#Step 4 Expected output
employersSummary = {'No.': ('Column', 'Sum')}
for output in range(14):
    total = 0
    for rrows in UniRows:
        if rrows[output] is not '':
            total += 1
    employersSummary[output] = (columns[output], total)
 print(employersSummary)

#Step 4 continued
twoColumns = {
0: 'AIG',
1: 'Baylor College of Medicine',
2: 'CGG',
3: 'Citi',
4: 'ExxonMobil',
5: 'Flow-Cal Inc.',
6: 'Global Shop Solutions',
7: 'Harris County CTS',
8: 'HCSS',
9: 'Hitachi Consulting',
10:'HP Inc.',
11: 'INT Inc.',
12: 'JPMorgan Chase & Co',
13: 'Leidos',
14: 'McKesson',
15: 'MRE Consulting Ltd.',
16: 'NetIQ',
17: 'PROS',
18: 'San Jacinto College',
19: 'SAS',
20: 'Smartbridge',
21: 'Sogeti USA',
22: 'Southwest Research Institute',
23: 'The Reynolds and Reynolds Company ',
24: 'UH Enterprise Systems',
25: 'U.S. Marine Corps',
26: 'ValuD Consuting LLC',
27: 'Wipro',}
for i in twoColumns:
    print(i, twoColumns[i])

#Step 4 continued

Uni2Rows = []
R2Rows = 0
for rows in filter:
    R2Rows += 1
    if R2Rows > 3 and R2Rows < 34 and rows[0] is not '':
        Uni2Rows.append(rows)


GradUnderGrad = {'No.': ('Company', 'Grad', 'UnderGrad')}
for i, out2put in enumerate(Uni2Rows):
    total = 0
    for roww in Uni2Rows [11:12]:
        if roww[out2put] is not '':
            total += 1
    GradUnderGrad.append(['No', twoColumns, UniRows[11], UniRows[12]])
 print(GradUnderGrad)
```

This is the outcome i want for the last step:

```
No Company Grad UnderGrad
0 AIG, 1, 1
1 Baylor College of Medicine, 0, 0
2 CGG, 1, 0
3 Citi, 0, 1
4 ExxonMobil, 0, 1
5 Flow-Cal Inc., 0, 1
6 Global Shop Solutions, 0, 1
7 Harris County CTS, 1, 1
8 HCSS, 1, 1
9 Hitachi Consulting, 1, 1
10 HP Inc., 1, 1
11 INT Inc., 1, 1
12 JPMorgan Chase & Co, 0, 1
13 Leidos, 1, 1
14 McKesson, 0, 1
15 MRE Consulting Ltd., 1, 1
16 NetIQ, 0, 1
17 PROS, 1, 1
18 San Jacinto College
19 SAS, 1, 1
20 Smartbridge, 1, 1
21 Sogeti USA, 1, 1
22 Southwest Research Institute, 1, 1
23 The Reynolds and Reynolds Company 0 1 24 UH Enterprise Systems, 1, 1
25 U.S. Marine Corps, 1, 1,
26 ValuD Consuting LLC, 0, 1
27 Wipro, 0 
Total 17 26
```

But this what i keep getting instead and its annoying:

```
 [No Company Grad UnderGrad]
```

My problem is on the last step for undergrad I am using a csv file. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? am I not merging columns correctly do i need a different code if anyone cane help me please do i need major help.

This is the link to the CSV file I'm using: https://github.com/ag0715/Assign3ddhudhudhuhsashdui3hrfuwhf94839fuh38u4fhui/blob/master/CSV%20FILE

Comment: What is `with open('scratch.csv', 'r', errors='replace') as progfile:
    progfile.close()` supposed to do?

Comment: More to the point: please give us a [mcve], not just a dump of all of your code. Especially when that code raises an immediate `IndentationError`. Especially when anyone who tries to fix it will be faced with the very first thing in the code being so baffling that it's impossible to tell what you were trying to d.

Comment: when i downloaded the file it actually wouldn't load and when i added that it started working I'm sure errors = replace is unnecessary in my python program my csv file is renamed to scratch thats why sorry for the confusion

Comment: I see I am sorry I was trying my best to show my work and what not to make it easier on people but i guess it didnt go as planned

Comment: Read the linked help page; it explains how to make your question easier on people. It really is surprisingly hard to figure out how to use SO effectively without help; that's why they wrote all those help pages.

Comment: @aaagggg1233 can you share the content of your `scratch.csv` file ?

Comment: @toheedNiaz yes this is the link to the csv file I'm using currently

Comment: @aaaggg12333 try the answer i gave below

Comment: @toheedNiaz  yes the link to the csv file is at the very end of my post it is the GitHub link. Here is the loink again. [link](https://github.com/ag0715/Assign3ddhudhudhuhsashdui3hrfuwhf94839fuh38u4fhui/blob/master/CSV%20FILE)

Comment: I have used that file please check the answer .

Comment: @toheedNiaz so i see your answer but its not giving me the output of just the company name, the value for grad, and value for undergrad too its printing everything out instead

Comment: @aaagggg1233 how would you translate `AIG,10,,,,Yes,,,Jr,,,MS,,` to AIG, 1, 1 ?? coz lets suppose if we make choice of first 3 then it can be AIG,10,Yes .

Comment: @toheedNiaz see thats what I don't comprehend how my value is suppose to output that. The assignment says to merge related columns but even then I'm still confused I've tried splicing and finding the value for the column phd and MS but nothing I am fully stuck now i have everything uploaded to my GitHub

Comment: @aaagggg1233 as per my understanding of the question code given below is something you need .

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using so complex approach for just reading some lines and finding the desired string.

Here is a sample code you can work with to achieve what you want :

```
import csv
import re

import os

repeatCheck = []
dataTOWorkWith = []
print(os.getcwd())
with open('task2.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=' ')
    idx = 0
    for line in list(csv_reader)[3:]:
            rowdata = ",".join(i for i in line)
            if "BOOTH" in rowdata :
                break
            if (not rowdata.startswith(","  or ".")) and (rowdata not in repeatCheck) and (rowdata != ""):
                dataTOWorkWith.append( str(idx) + "," + (re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.,]', ' ', rowdata )))
                idx+=1
                repeatCheck.append(rowdata)
with open('task4.csv', 'w') as csv_file:

    banner = "No Company Grad UnderGrad"
    csv_file.write(",".join(x for x in banner.split(" "))+"\n")
    print(banner)
    for data in dataTOWorkWith :
        rowToPrint  = " ".join(data.split(",")[0:2])+" "
        rowdataToAppend = ",".join(data.split(",")[0:2])+","
        underGrand = "".join(data.split(",")[7:10]).rstrip()
        Grand = "".join(data.split(",")[11:12]).rstrip()
        if Grand != "" :
            rowToPrint+=str(1)+" "
            rowdataToAppend+=str(1)+","
        else:
            rowToPrint += str(0) + " "
            rowdataToAppend += str(0) + ","

        if underGrand != "" :
            rowdataToAppend += str(1) + ","
            rowToPrint+=str(1)
        else:
            rowdataToAppend += str(0) + ","
            rowToPrint += str(0)
        grandUgrad = Grand + "," + underGrand
        print(rowToPrint)
        csv_file.write(rowdataToAppend+"\n")
```

**Output**

```
No Company Grad UnderGrad
0 AIG 1 1
1 Baylor   College   of   Medicine 0 0
2 CGG 1 0
3 Citi 0 1
4 ExxonMobil 0 1
5 Flow Cal   Inc. 0 1
6 Global   Shop   Solutions 0 1
7 Harris   County   CTS 1 1
8 HCSS 1 1
9 Hitachi   Consulting 1 1
10 HP   Inc. 1 1
11 INT   Inc. 1 1
12 JPMorgan   Chase       Co 0 1
13 Leidos 1 1
14 McKesson 0 1
15 MRE   Consulting   Ltd. 1 1
16 NetIQ 0 1
17 PROS 1 1
18 San   Jacinto   College       1 1
19 SAS 1 1
20 Smartbridge 1 1
21 Sogeti   USA 1 1
22 Southwest   Research   Institute 1 1
23 The   Reynolds   and   Reynolds   Company 0 1
24 UH   Enterprise   Systems 1 1
25 U.S.   Marine   Corps 1 1
26 ValuD   Consuting   LLC 0 1
27 Wipro 0 1
```

Comment: @aaagggg1233 take a look at solution now and let me know if it works for you